# Is ActiveRecord Store the right choice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ive been working on an app for table-top RPG games that is meant to be universal for all games.  Currently the way im doing this is with a combination of a specific tables for each game (with columns for each attribute) and also making universal tables for things like equipment, attacks, etc.  This is working but the tables are getting a little complex and hard to handle with multiple nested relationships.

I stumbled upon rails ActiveRecord Store and think this is a better option as I could serialize the attributes into a single column and the views would handle saving and loading the right variables from the serialized column.

Im wondering if I am missing something or is this a valid option?

Answer (score -1):

1. It sounds like a great option. Write lots of tests. Try it out.
2. There's nothing wrong with hundreds of tables. It can help in terms of organization to separate models into namespaces.

Comment: Luckily I haven't gotten too far and switching wont be that much of an issue, maybe set me back a day or two